# Is it possible to initialize a private array in a header file with a member which is initialized in the constructor? c++

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to declare an array in a header file but I would like have the size of the array declared when the class is constructed. Is this possible? I found a lot of array declarations on this site but not this in particular. When I try the code below I get the error "array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token"

foo.h

```
class foo{
   private:
      uint16_t _size;
      uint16_t array[_size];
   public:
      foo(uint16_t size);
      virtual ~foo();
}
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
foo::foo(uint16_t size)
:_size(size)  
{ 
}
```

Comment: use vector? vector is dynamic array in C++.

Comment: Thanks billz but I am trying to stay away from vectors if possible!

Comment: Vectors do exactly what you want, so why not use them?

Comment: John is absolutely right about vectors doing precisely what you want; in addition, vectors do it as efficiently as the arrays, so there's very little reason not to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One particular way of doing it is this

```
class foo
{
public:
   foo(uint16_t size);
private:
   uint16_t _size;
   uint16_t* array;
};

foo::foo(uint16_t size) :_size(size)
{
    array = new int[_size];
}
```

That will allow you to dynamically create an array at runtime, I would suggest you use a std::vector though because generally they are a lot better than arrays in C++(IMO) but if you have a particular reason to use an array thats the way I'd do it. Using static means that if you wanted to use that class elsewhere then _size would share the same values between instances also I wouldn't think that would compile because only static functions can access static members.

EDT: in my haste to answer I forgot to say that you should add a destructor in your class to destroy the array when the class goes out of scope something like this

```
foo:~foo()
{
    delete[] array;
}
```

Got downvoted because I never added in a reference to rule of three. Ideally you shouldn't use dynamically initialised arrays anyway and just use vectors here's the link to the rule of three [C++ rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

Comment: It may be a good idea to point out that a destructor should also be defined in this solution.

Comment: actually should follow rule of three

Comment: Added before your comment :P but yeah you're right I shouldn't assume that people know about about destructors.

Comment: I don't think its really fair to downvote this because I didn't add in a copy constructor and assignment operator

Comment: @DavidTr It's quite a serious memory leak and a idiom we should teach beginners.

Comment: Yes but you can't overload them with this serious knowledge straight away, I understand that it can cause serious problems but usually only in large projects and as a beginner I feel its not necessary to overload them with this information. You're right though in future a reference wouldn't go astray.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation this works! I am targeting a device with a small amount of memory, which is why I am leaning towards arrays. I am also using a lot of c code as well.

Comment: I will edit with my destructor. I didn't see one in the other posts and didn't add it here. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Sam. if you do go with this solution then make sure you do understand the rule of three. Vectors interface with C code perfectly, and a typical vector implementation will use only four bytes more than the code above. You get a lot of extra power, flexibility and safety for those four bytes.

Comment: No problem, like Alex Chamberlain said you should probably look into the rule of three as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will defiantly look into the rule of 3. I am testing my program in windows before cross compiling and will probably not include vectors as they are not currently supported with my cross-compile setup. I will eventually hard code the vector size but for testing this will help tremendously. Thanks Again!

Comment: @Sam I strongly advise a better cross compile setup.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should use `std::vector<uint16_t>`: it lets you decide the size dynamically, like this:

```
vector<uint16_t> array;
...
foo(size_t size) : array(size) {}
...
```

Alternatively, you can use a pointer instead of the array, allocate it in the constructor, and  delete in the destructor:

```
uint16_t *array;
...
foo(size_t size) : array(new uint16_t[size]) {}
...
~foo() {delete[] array;}
```

This is not as good, because once you define the destructor, you need to deal with the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

You could use template parameter to define array size, if you really have to use array:

```
template<size_t N>
class foo{
private:
    uint16_t array[N];

public:
    foo()
    {
    }
};

foo<3> f;
```

`std::vector` is dynamic array in C++, it provides rich interfaces to operate array, there is little reason not to use `std::vector`.

```
class foo{
private:
    std::vector<uint16_t> array;
   
public:
    foo(uint16_t size) : array(size)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The size of an array must be a compile time constant. In your case the size of an instance of class foo depends on the size of the array. If you know the size of the contained array at compile time for every use of class `foo`, then you could use a template:

```
template <size_t N>
class foo {
    uint16_t array[N];
public:
    foo() {}
};
```

Otherwise you should use the resizable array offered by C++: `std::vector`:

```
class foo {
    std::size_t size;
    std::vector<uint16_t> array;
public:
    foo(std::size_t size_) 
    : size(size_)
    , array(size_)
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you initialize a static variable. Here's how (usually in the CPP file):

```
uint16_t foo::_size = /* something */;
```

But I don't think you want a static variable.
I'd suggest you to go with dynamic allocated arrays instead:

```
class foo{
   private:
      uint16_t _size;
      uint16_t* array;
      static uint16_t* copy(uint16_t* a, uint16_t s) {
          if (!a) return 0;
          uint16_t* ret = new uint16_t[s];
          for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) ret[i] = a[i];
          return ret;
      }
   public:
      foo(const foo& f) : _size(f._size), array(0) { array = copy(f.array, f._size); }
      foo(uint16_t size = 0) : _size(size), array(0) {
          if (size == 0) return;
          array = new uint16_t[_size];
      }
      ~foo() { delete[] array; }
}
```

Even a better solution would be to use one of the standard library containers such as `std::vector`.

Comment: -1 the OP didn't mention having a static variable. The answer also violates the Rule of Three and doesn't explain the OP should use a vector.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, [it did mentioned a static variable](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15467152/1). And my revision suggest the use of a container.

Comment: Would you agree that this solution violates the rule of three?

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector.

```
class foo{
   private:
      std::vector<uint16_t> array;
   public:
      foo(uint16_t size)
};

foo::foo(uint16_t size) : array(size)  
{ 
}
```